# Cannot get selected value of Select2 dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use [Select2 Dropdown](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) dropdownlist in my MVC project as shown below. Although I can pass the "query" parameter via AJAX by setting it directly, I cannot get the selected text or value of dropdownlist in the data section below. How to get it?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StudentId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
    new { style ="width: 100%;" } )

$("#StudentId").select2({
   multiple: false,
   placeholder: "Select",
   allowClear: true,
   tags: true,

   ajax: {
       url: '/Grade/StudentLookup',
       dataType: 'json',
       delay: 250,

       data: function (params) {
           return {
               //q: params.Name, // search term
               //page: params.page
               query : 'test' //this parameter can be passed via AJAX
               //!!! but I cannot get the selected text or value of dropdownlist 
           };
       },              

       processResults: function (data, page) {
           var newData = [];
           $.each(data, function (index, item) {
               newData.push({
                   id: item.Id,     //id part present in data 
                   text: item.Name  //string to be displayed
               });
           });
           return { results: newData };
       },
       cache: true
   },
   escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
   minimumInputLength: 0, //for listing all, set : 0
   maximumInputLength: 20, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**============================== S O L V E D ==============================**

Here is the solution of the problem:

In order to send the text value in Select2 via AJAX use **params.term** in the data section as shown below. Many thanks to @DavidDomain as his answer also very useful in order to use selected index change.

```
//code omitted for brevity
data: function (params) {
   return {
             query: params.term, // search term
             page: params.page
           };
   }, 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply listen to the `select2:select` event to get the selected item.

> [**Events**](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events)
>
> **select2:select**
>
> *Triggered whenever a result is selected.*

```js
var select2 = $(".select2");

select2.select2({
  multiple: false,
  placeholder: "Select",
  allowClear: true,
  tags: true,
  width: "180"
});

function onSelect(evt) {
  console.log($(this).val());
}

select2.on('select2:select', onSelect)
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2">
  <option value="item-1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="item-4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="item-5">Item 5</option>
  <option value="item-6">Item 6</option>
  <option value="item-7">Item 7</option>
  <option value="item-8">Item 8</option>
  <option value="item-9">Item 9</option>
  <option value="item-10">Item 10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect answer. I just missed something and could not get the selected value on the **data** section in AJAX. How can I catch it in there?

Comment: I created a variable var selectedText = ""; and then set it **selectedText = $(this).val();** in function onSelect(evt){}, and then try to assign this value to **query: selectedText** in the data section, but cannot set query parameter. Any idea?

Comment: So you want to pass the input text to the ajax call as a parameter ?

Comment: Use a function for the `url` parameter in the `ajax` section like so `url: function (params) { return '/some/url/' + params.term; }`. This should do it. The query parameters will be passed in through the params option.

Comment: Sorry David, but I have not managed to pass the selected Text value even if using it. I think I cannot use the function in your last comment properly. Could you please try it on your code snippet? I just want to set or pass the Text value of selected record :( Many thanks for your helps... Voted+

Comment: On the other hand, there are some code to get the selected property value as **$("#StudentId").select2("val", ["Text", "Value"])**, but it only gets Id and if I can get Text value the problem will be solved. Any idea?